# How to find out the mac adress of a device I am communicating with via a socket

Tags: android, sockets

Hey my android connect commuicates with a special device.

The remote device is connected to my home network as well as the android device. They communicate via a socket. How can I find out the mac adress of that device now?

Thanks,
Best regards

Comment: Found it by myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240706/detecting-android-devices-connected-to-wifi

Answer (score 1):

The Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) is what maps ethernet addresses (the MAC address) to IP addresses (the 192.168.2.115 one). You can examine your devices arp table using the `arp` command. For instance:

```
% adb shell arp -a
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
fox.home.network (192.168.0.1) at 00:0x:yz:00:01:00 [ether]  on eth0
```

You can also use snmp to examine the routing tables on routers on your network to fetch arp/ip maps quite often.

Comment: Yes but I needit it programmatically by the app not by console. You can parse /proc/net/arp for it.

Answer (score 0):

A socket does not provide access to MAC addresses. You need the device's IP address on the network in order to communicate with it.

Comment: Actually i got it. Its 192.168.2.115, so its local. What can I do next?